# Magento quick getResourceModel question

Tags: php, database, magento, mage

What class (if any) is called with this line of code?

```
Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_invoice_collection')
```

Essentially I"m trying to figure out what database table is accessed with this resource model and how I can tweak that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The class you are looking for is this:

```
Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Order_Invoice_Collection
```

located in `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Mysql4/Order/Invoice/Collection.php`.

If you take a look at the configuration for the sales module `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/config.xml`, you can see the table name in the definition of the resource models:

```
<config>
    <global>
        <models>
            <sales_mysql4>
                <entities>
                    ...
                    <invoice><table>sales_flat_invoice</table></invoice>
                    ...
                </entities>
            </sales_mysql4>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

To learn more about how Magento interacts with the database, you should read about models, resource models, and collections:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-5-magento-models-and-orm-basics

Comment: Ah beat me to it, and with better formatting. Though, shouldn't the relevant portion of the config file be the <resourceModel> tag?

Comment: Well, you are more correct, heh. The <resourceModel> tag points to the <sales_mysql4> tag, which contains the <class> tag that ultimately points to the directory in question.

Answer (score 5):

Try this to get the class resulting from a statement:

```
$obj = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_invoice_collection');
print get_class($obj);
```

Answer (score 4):

In this instance it is loading

```
code/Core/Mage/Sales/Model/Mysql4/Order/Invoice/Collection.php
```

which is class name:

```
Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Order_Invoice_Collection
```

This can be determined by looking at the config.xml:

```
code/Core/Mage/Sales/etc/config.xml.
```

In it under the models tag is the sales tag, which you know from 'sales' before the slash in the string. There it defines the resource model as sales_mysql4. 
So, if you call:

```
Mage::getResourceModel('module/everything_else')
```

the file loaded will be:

```
Module/Model/{contents of resourceModel tag}/Everything/Else.php
```

Hope that helps.